# Is better for security to not run Nginx and Backend inside docker but use docker only for database and not external exposed services?

Tags: .net, docker, nginx

I'm not a Docker specialist, I know how to install, configure and do only basic Docker hardening based on Docker official documentation.

I know nothing about AppArmor,SELinux and GRSEC.

But i need to put my C# app backend in production; My C# backend app have file upload features too.

In my case, is better to use docker and docker-compose only for not internet public exposed server/services and use Docker only more "internally" for thinks like database etc? And keep in bare metal (on host) all things that can be more critical like images and video converters, exposed servers like nginx etc?

This can reduce attack surface, i think. I'm right?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you assume that this would reduce your attack surface? Have you considered rootless docker and using multiple users for the different images to separate privileges?

Comment: Some tips: 1. Use `docker compose` instead of `docker-compose`, which is a native plugin. 2. File upload management should be done in C# then or similar, not on Docker. 3. You should consider the legal matters when you let users upload content, if it's public. It also depends on your jurisdiction.

Comment: @SirMuffington C# is a programming language. Docker is not. I don't see the relevance of discussing language; file uploads can be done safely in many languages, with or without docker.

Comment: @vidarlo I don't get what you mean by that. You're misinterpreting my comment somewhy/somehow

Comment: @SirMuffington *File upload management should be done in C# then or similar, not on Docker* - I simply don't grok the comparison you do here.

Comment: @vidarlo that was just a suggestion..

Answer (score 2):

Docker will help you isolate your app (if configured right) from the environment it is running in.

For example, if you have a Linux server that is the only machine in its network and the only thing you will use it for is to deploy your web app, then there is no need for Docker here (from a security perspective).

If you plan to have separate applications running on the same machine (e.g MySQL + Nginx + Redis) then from a security perspective, having them in Docker containers to isolate the ability of an attacker to move around after exploiting one of the services can be recommended.

I recommend you take a look [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/) on how to properly secure your container.